# After upgrading PHP 5.6.16 to 7.2.9 SoapClient::__doRequest() not working always returns empty response

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

After upgrade PHP 7.2.9 the SoapClient stopped working properly and always returns blank.

## Client file

```php
<?php

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
$xml .= '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">';
$xml .= '<SOAP-ENV:Body>';
$xml .= '<Authenticate>';
$xml .= '<Username>guest</Username>';
$xml .= '<Password>welcome</Password>';
$xml .= '<Locale>en_US</Locale>';
$xml .= '<ValidityInMin>60</ValidityInMin>';
$xml .= '<isGlobal>true</isGlobal>';
$xml .= '</Authenticate>';
$xml .= '</SOAP-ENV:Body>';
$xml .= '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

$url='https://test.mylocal.com/soapresponse.php?actionkey=authenticate';


$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=>FALSE,
        'verify_peer_name'=>FALSE,
        )
);

$soapOptions = array(
    'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2,
    'location'=>$url,
    'uri'=>$url,
    'exceptions'=> 0,
    'trace'=>true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
    
);
$client = new SoapClient("test.wsdl",$soapOptions);

$xmlstr = $client->__doRequest($xml,$url,'',1);

var_dump($client->__getLastResponseHeaders());
var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
?>
```

## SOAP server file

```php
<?php

class AuthenticateService {
    
    public function authenticate($requestData){
        try{
           // do some business logics and the result will be framed like below
            
            $cert=Array();
            $cert[0]=new StdClass();
            $cert[0]->SPCertificate="test111";
            $cert[0]->SPLearnerLicense="test234";
            $cert[0]->SPAdminLicense="lic4334";
            $cert[0]->SPLearnerInfo="ssdsfr834544";
            $cert[0]->Name="test";
            $cert[0]->UserName="test";
            $cert[0]->UserId=44; 
            
            $outData=$cert;
            
            return $outData;
        }catch(Exception $e){
            
            throw new SoapFault("SPLMS",$e->getMessage());

        }
    }
    
    
}
$server = new SoapServer("test.wsdl",array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$server->setClass("AuthenticateService");
$server->handle();

?>
```

## WSDL file

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions name='authenticate' targetNamespace="https://test.mylocal.com/wsdl/wsdlschema.xsd" 
    xmlns:expertus='https://test.mylocal.com/sites/all/modules/core/exp_sp_core/wsdl/wsdlschema.xsd'
    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
    xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

    <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="https://test.mylocal.com/wsdl/wsdlschema.xsd">
         <xsd:include schemaLocation="/wsdl/wsdlschema.xsd"/>    
         <xsd:complexType name="AuthResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name='SPCertificate' type='xsd:string'/>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:complexType name="validateUserRequest">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" /> 
                <xsd:element name="pass" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="validateEmail">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="email" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="validateCaptcha">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="captcha" type="xsd:string" /> 
                <xsd:element name="captcha_entered" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        
        <xsd:complexType name="Authenticate">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name='Username' type='xsd:string' />
            <xsd:element name='Password' type='xsd:string' />
            <xsd:element name='Locale' type='xsd:string' />
            <xsd:element name='ValidityInMin' type='xsd:string' />
            <xsd:element name='isGlobal' type='xsd:string' minOccurs='0' />
        </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>
     
     <xsd:complexType name="Certificate">
      <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="string">
            <xsd:attribute name="Id" type="string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="UserName" type="string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="string" /> 
        </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
        
                        
       </xsd:schema>
     </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name='authenticateServiceRequest'>
         <wsdl:part name="Authenticate" type="expertus:Authenticate"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name='authenticateServiceResponse'>
        <wsdl:part name='Certificate' type='expertus:AuthResponse' />
        <wsdl:part name='Token' type='xsd:string' />
    </wsdl:message>
    
    <wsdl:message name="ValidateUserServiceRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="ValidateUserService" type="expertus:validateUserRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ValidateUserServiceResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="ValidateUserService" element="xsd:string" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GenerateCaptchaServiceRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="GenerateCaptcha" element="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GenerateCaptchaServiceResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="GenerateCaptcha" element="xsd:string" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ValidateCaptchaServiceRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="ValidateCaptcha" type="expertus:validateCaptcha"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ValidateCaptchaServiceResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="ValidateCaptcha" element="xsd:string" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ValidateUsernameServiceRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="ValidateUsername" type="expertus:validateUserRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ValidateUsernameServiceResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="ValidateUsername" element="xsd:string" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ValidateEmailRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="ValidateEmail" type="expertus:validateEmail"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ValidateEmailResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="ValidateEmail" element="xsd:string" />
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name='AuthenticateServicePortType'>
        <wsdl:operation name='authenticate'>
            <wsdl:input name="authenticateServiceReq" message='expertus:authenticateServiceRequest' />
            <wsdl:output name="authenticateServiceRes" message='expertus:authenticateServiceResponse' />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    
    <wsdl:portType name="ValidateUserServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="validateUser">
            <wsdl:input name="ValidateUserServiceReq" message="expertus:ValidateUserServiceRequest" />
            <wsdl:output name="ValidateUserServiceRes" message="expertus:ValidateUserServiceResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    
    <wsdl:portType name="GenerateCaptchaServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="generateCaptcha">
            <wsdl:input name="GenerateCaptchaServiceReq" message="expertus:GenerateCaptchaServiceRequest" />
            <wsdl:output name="GenerateCaptchaServiceRes" message="expertus:GenerateCaptchaServiceResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    
    <wsdl:portType name="ValidateCaptchaServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="validateCaptcha">
            <wsdl:input name="ValidateCaptchaServiceReq" message="expertus:ValidateCaptchaServiceRequest" />
            <wsdl:output name="ValidateCaptchaServiceRes" message="expertus:ValidateCaptchaServiceResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    
    <wsdl:portType name="ValidateUsernameServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="validateUsername">
            <wsdl:input name="ValidateUsernameServiceReq" message="expertus:ValidateUsernameServiceRequest" />
            <wsdl:output name="ValidateUsernameServiceRes" message="expertus:ValidateUsernameServiceResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:portType name="ValidateEmailPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="validateEmail">
            <wsdl:input name="ValidateEmailReq" message="expertus:ValidateEmailRequest" />
            <wsdl:output name="ValidateEmailRes" message="expertus:ValidateEmailResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name='AuthenticateServiceBinding' type='expertus:AuthenticateServicePortType'>
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name='authenticate'>
            <soap:operation soapAction=" " style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use='literal' />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use='literal' />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    
    <wsdl:binding name='ValidateUserServiceBinding' type='expertus:ValidateUserServicePortType'>
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name='validateUser'>
            <soap:operation soapAction=" " style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use='literal' />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use='literal' />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    
    <wsdl:binding name='GenerateCaptchaServiceBinding' type='expertus:GenerateCaptchaServicePortType'>
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name='generateCaptcha'>
            <soap:operation soapAction=" " style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use='literal' />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use='literal'  />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    
    <wsdl:binding name='ValidateCaptchaServiceBinding' type='expertus:ValidateCaptchaServicePortType'>
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name='validateCaptcha'>
            <soap:operation soapAction=" " style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use='literal'  />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use='literal'  />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    
    <wsdl:binding name='ValidateUsernameServiceBinding' type='expertus:ValidateUsernameServicePortType'>
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name='validateUsername'>
            <soap:operation soapAction=" " style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use='literal'  />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use='literal'  />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name='ValidateEmailBinding' type='expertus:ValidateEmailPortType'>
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name='validateEmail'>
            <soap:operation soapAction=" " style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use='literal'  />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use='literal'  />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name='AuthenticateService'>
        <wsdl:port name='AuthenticateServicePort' binding='expertus:AuthenticateServiceBinding'>
            <soap:address location='https://test.mylocal.com/sites/all/services/Service.php' />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="ValidateUserServicePort" binding="expertus:ValidateUserServiceBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://test.mylocal.com/sites/all/services/Service.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="GenerateCaptchaServicePort" binding="expertus:GenerateCaptchaServiceBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://test.mylocal.com/sites/all/services/Service.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="ValidateCaptchaServicePort" binding="expertus:ValidateCaptchaServiceBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://test.mylocal.com/sites/all/services/Service.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="ValidateUsernameServicePort" binding="expertus:ValidateUsernameServiceBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://test.mylocal.com/sites/all/services/Service.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="ValidateEmailPort" binding="expertus:ValidateEmailBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://test.mylocal.com/sites/all/services/Service.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Still the same code works fine in 5.6.16 only in 7.2.9 it is not working the response header will send 200 status but the response body is empty.

In the server side if i use SoapVar() i am getting the response in xml with empty body like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body/></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you have Soap extension installed and showing in the list of enabled extensions for PHP 7.2, both console and web? Looks like you do, but worth a check. Generally, when body is empty means that your format of it is invalid. Since you have access to the server you might try to debug it in a local environment and see what’s happening.

Comment: Don't build XML by string concatenation, and don't disable peer verification. Are you going to share the results of your `var_dump()` statements?

Comment: Hi Daniel, soap extension is enabled and it shows up in the phpinfo. On my further debug in the server side the xml is framed well when using SoapVar but it is not bind with response.